# cmake build error on build process

Tags: cmake

I get this error on build process with cmake it tells me that

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:223:
  Parse error.  Function missing ending ")".  End of file reached.
```

Here is my code:

```
    if( make_release_only)

 endif()

# I don't plan on debugging this, so make it a release build.
if( NOT CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES "Release" )
    set( CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "RelWithDebInfo" )
endif()

if( ZD_CMAKE_COMPILER_IS_GNUCXX_COMPATIBLE )
    set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wall -Wextra" )
    endif()

    if( NOT PROFILE )
        set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fomit-frame-pointer" )
    endif()
    if check_cxx_compiler_flag( -Wno-array-bounds HAVE_NO_ARRAY_BOUNDS )

    endif()
    if ( HAVE_NO_ARRAY_BOUNDS )

    endif()
    if ( set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-array-bounds" )
    endif()
```

Comment: Simple typo... Two opening parentheses on the penultimate line.

Comment: To locate such errors in the future you may comment code from the end up to the place where you think you mistaken. If error still exists, then you not yet comment it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ( set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-array-bounds" )
```

This line has two open parenthesis "(", but only one close paranthesis ")". Also, you cannot do `if` on a `set` command, so the line doesn't make much sense. Maybe you meant to not have the `if` there ?

```
if ( HAVE_NO_ARRAY_BOUNDS )
    set( CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -Wno-array-bounds" )
endif()
```

Comment: okay is their another way to fix this i'm sorry i am just learning alot in cmake in the last 2 weeks and i am just stuck  i am sorry for this its just hard sometimes .

Comment: is there a reason you can't fix it this way?

Comment: thanks this helped me out.

Comment: I know i am saying the same thing as the new edited question but you all have put it on hold so i did not know if anybody would see the new edit but  my other question is. unable to start program cannot find file specified

I am build a source port test and I am stuck on these issues. i get this error when I debug the ALL_BUILD it contains the source files and resource files for the project but it still does not let me debug the project.